# Running Exchange Powershell script from a batch file: command doesn't work. What's wrong with my syntax?

Tags: powershell, scripting, exchange-2013, batch

Coming from this question here: [How to create a script for Exchange Powershell to modify settings for all shared mailboxes?](https://serverfault.com/questions/799097/how-to-create-a-script-for-exchange-powershell-to-modify-settings-for-all-shared)

Here is my Powershell script (scroll right to see all):

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox

Foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) { 
    Set-Mailbox $Mailbox -MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled $True -MessageCopyForSendOnBehalfEnabled $True
    }
```

It works fine on its own if launched from an Exchange Management Shell window.

But I want to launch it from a batch file, so I found the following Microsoft page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123798%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#RunScript

Following the guide there, I created this batch file (scroll right to see all):

```
PowerShell.exe -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto; 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\enablesentforshared.ps1'"
```

One thing I added which was not specified in the instructions is single quotes around the full path to the script I want to run.  Without the single quotes I was getting an error about `C:\Program` not being a recognized cmdlet or script.

Anyway, when I run this batch file, the terminal window opens, then changes to a Powershell window, and the path name to the script gets printed out to the screen, but it prints out BEFORE the `[PS]` prompt, and nothing actually gets executed.

This is what my Powershell window looks like after executing the batch file:

```
VERBOSE: Connecting to exchangeserver.domain.com
VERBOSE: Connected to exchangeserver.domain.com
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\enablesentforshared.ps1
[PS] C:\Users\Admin.domain>
```

And there is no indication that the script has actually run.

So what have I got wrong here?  I tried changing the `.` to a `&` based on some googling I did, but then that gives me an error about `Connect-ExchangeServer` being an unrecognized command, so I think the `.` is closer to being correct.

Comment: That looks like it should work. Does your script have any output when you run it from powershell normally?

Comment: So, there is definitely an output.  Since I've run the script successfully before (without the batch file), then whenever I try to run the script again I get a bunch of notices that there are no settings to change (because I already changed them).  But anyway you got me thinking... since I have the script in the Exchange Server `\bin` directory, I don't use the full path when running from the powershell terminal, just the name `enablesentforshared.ps1`.  It works like this from the powershell terminal.  So, I tried removing the path from the batch file, *and it also works now!*

Comment: Also, if I try running the full path, even from the powershell terminal, `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\enablesentforshared.ps1` it exhibits the same behavior as the batch file, telling me that `C:\Program` is not recognized.  So if I try putting quotes at the terminal, like `'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\enablesentforshared.ps1'` or `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\enablesentforshared.ps1"`, it again has the same behavior as the batch file, just spitting the full path back out at me and not actually running the script.  Strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (added dotsourcing of the second script):

```
PowerShell.exe -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto; . 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\enablesentforshared.ps1'"
```

Comment: Yup, that little `.` did the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Bat file script including send mail parameter. This bat file work on my window server 2016 and exchange server 2016.

```
PowerShell.exe -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto; . C:\Script\Get-ExchangeEnvironmentReport.ps1 -HTMLReport C:\Script\Get-exchangeReport.html -SendMail:$true -MailFrom:Admin@domain.com -MailTo:user1@domain.com -MailServer:mail.domain.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

I do this in a BAT file:

powershell -psconsolefile "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Bin\exshell.psc1" -noexit "& Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics"
pause